# I want to make the program work so that the case of the character is insensitive

Tags: java

The way the program is supposed to work initially is to ask the user to input a string, followed by a character and then tests whether the string starts with that character. The case of the character should be irrelevant. I have had a good go myself it runs but doesn't meet specifications. For example when I run it and type "HELLO" as the first input and the second input is the character "h" lowercase it does not say true. Even though "h" is lowercase I still want my program to take it in to account. I am new to using objects of string with methods. I want the program to ignore the case.

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class Page189Question2aAnd2b
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   String a = new String();
   String b = new String();



   System.out.println("Input a string:");
   a = EasyScanner.nextString();
   a.equalsIgnoreCase(a);
   System.out.println("Enter a single character ");
   b = EasyScanner.nextString();
   b.equalsIgnoreCase(b);

   if(a.startsWith(b))
   {
     System.out.println(a.startsWith(b));
     //System.out.println(a.equalsIgnoreCase(b));
   }

   }
   }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by a.equalsIgnoreCase(a);?

Comment: You could call `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` on both the Strings before calling `startsWith()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`equalsIgnoreCase` just returns a boolean, which indicates, whether two strings are equal if the case of the strings is not considered.

What you need is

```
String aLower = a.toLowerCase();
String bLower = b.toLowerCase();  
if(aLower.startsWith(bLower))
{
  // do something
}
```

That way you just convert both strings to lower case to compare them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
            System.out.println((a.toLowerCase()).startsWith(b.toLowerCase()));
```